# How to use JavaScript variable in Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to pass my JS variable into razor, my script fragment:

```
 select: function (event, ui) {                            
   var docID = ui.item.DoctorCode;

    @{ 
      string org_code = _unitOfWork.Doctors.GetById("").OrganizationCode;
     }

       doctorOrgLabel.text('@org_code'); 
    }
```

In `GetById()` method i want to pass JS variable `docID`. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: once your view is rendered you don't interact with it again.  so you can't do what you're trying to do that i'm aware of.  you'd need to setup ajax calls if you need more data based off of a selected value or just load a json object you can reference later.

Comment: Thanks! loading json object works for me!

Answer (score 7):

> I try to pass my JS variable into razor

This sentence makes strictly no sense at all.

Razor is a view engine used by the ASP.NET MVC framework running on the server to produce some HTML template.

javascript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client. Once the HTML template is rendered to the client and javascript starts to execute there's no longer such notion as Razor.

If you want to pass some javascript variable to the server you have a couple of options:

- make an AJAX call to the server
- set the value of this variable in some hidden field inside a form and submit this form
- use `window.location.href` to redirect to the server and passing the variable as query string parameter
- store the javascript variable in a cookie which will be sent to the server on subsequent requests

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please provide an example of any of the options? I'm not sure how to use Ajax.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you could use the `$.ajax` function which is pretty well documented here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/