# How to convert javascript variable to a Razor variable?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

lets say i have a javascript variable such as:

```
var something = "information";
```

I now want to do things with this variable in Razor

```
@string something2 = something;
```

I would like to do something similar to the above code, any ideas?

Comment: This won't work. For more information, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991161/pass-js-variable-or-inout-value-to-razor, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500941/setting-razor-variables-in-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011016/how-to-use-javascript-variable-in-razor and try to understand the basic principles of client and server side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wont be able to convert JavaScript variable to a Razor variable. Where **Razor variable is handled by Razor engine** where as **JavaScript on the other hand is a client side language running on the client.**

Razor is a view engine used by the ASP.NET MVC framework running on the server to produce some HTML template.

Comment: Thats fair enough its answered my question in one way